# How to use rvest to scrape this table? Loop?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to 'scrape' some data from a website (names). I know how to get the first name on the list -- but there are a few thousand names that I need to save in the same way.

Here's my code:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url <- ("https://www.advokatsamfundet.se/Advokatsamfundet-engelska/Find-a-lawyer/Search-result/?firstname=&lastname=&companyname=&postalcity=&country=4401&spokenlanguage=&sortingcity=&positions=102001")


names <- url %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
    html_elements(xpath = '/html/body/div[3]/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a') %>% 
  html_text()
```

This gives me the first name on the list as it is in the table.

The names follows this simple structure:

```
'/html/body/div[3]/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a')
'/html/body/div[3]/div/div/main/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/a')
'/html/body/div[3]/div/div/main/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/a')
```

Notice that we increase by 1 for each name. It ends on 6212.

I started working on a function, but I'm not getting anywhere.
Here it is anyway -- but it doen't work and I think it may be a dead end.

```
scrape_fun <- function(.x){
  names %>% 
  html_elements(xpath = '/html/body/div[3]/div/div/main/div[2]/div[.x]/div[1]/a') %>% 
  html_text()
}
```

Any advice on how get it to work? All 6212 names?

Comment: You could use a for loop.,.  But you may find a useful function in the NHSdatadictionaRy package, although it is mainly for <table> rather than <a.> Tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following css pattern to select them

```
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)

people <- read_html("https://www.advokatsamfundet.se/Advokatsamfundet-engelska/Find-a-lawyer/Search-result/?firstname=&lastname=&companyname=&postalcity=&country=4401&spokenlanguage=&sortingcity=&positions=102001") %>%
  html_nodes(".c-list .o-flex__item:nth-child(1) > [href]") %>%
  html_text()
```

This selects for the `href` attribute, within first child elements (the left most *column*) with class `o-flex__item`, which have a shared parent with class `c-list`. The `>` is a child combinator specifying that what is on the right is a direct child of what is on the left. It is a more efficient and specific combinator than using a descendant combinator (which can go down nested levels). Class css selectors are the second fastest method after id.

Another pattern might have been `html_nodes("[href*=personid]")` - this selects for all `href` attributes containing the string `personid`.

Comment: Whilst looking like a table it is not an actual html table.

Comment: That worked like a charm. I figured there would be a better way. How did you know what to select? Experience? I tried the 'selector gadget' -- but that didn't find anything.

Comment: Experience. You might like to read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url <- ("https://www.advokatsamfundet.se/Advokatsamfundet-engelska/Find-a-lawyer/Search-result/?firstname=&lastname=&companyname=&postalcity=&country=4401&spokenlanguage=&sortingcity=&positions=102001")

names<- NULL
for (i in 1:6212){
names[i]<- url %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
    html_elements(xpath = paste0("'/html/body/div[3]/div/div/main/div[2]/div[",i,"]/div[1]/a'") )%>% 
  html_text()

}
```

Comment: Looks like something I'm looking for, but returns: Error: object 'null' not found

Comment: Sorry NULL not null.

Comment: This just gives me a value that says NULL and the message: Error in xml_nodeset(nodes) : 
  VECTOR_ELT() can only be applied to a 'list', not a 'character'

Comment: I'm going to need to move from my phone to something I can type on!... Will be back soon